# Was this comment constructive whatsoever?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

A couple of days back, I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around/8283720#comment25253152_8283720) comment as 'Not Constructive':

Note: the comment has been edited since this post was created.

> @RichardJ.RossIII NO! NO NO NO! BAD! HACK! I BANISH YOU DEFINING DEMON! THOU SHALT NOT ABUSE THE PREPROCESSOR IN THIS WAY! Whenever there is a preprocessor and non-preprocessor way of accomplishing a single task, ALWAYS pick the non-preprocessor way! Using the preprocessor is ALWAYS a HACK and RARELY NECESSARY. – ArtOfWarfare Jun 30 at 19:00

Not only was the comment extremely opinionated, it was all-caps, eye catching, and didn't add to the answer whatsoever in my opinion.

However, my flag was simply 'declined', and the comment remains to this day.

What's the deal here?

Comment: Appears to start off more tongue-in-cheek than offensive or whatever, the caps for emphasis at the end maybe a symptom of the former little rant. Certainly not the _most_ constructive way to get one's point across, but _not_ constructive? I don't know about that.

Comment: To me, that's very valuable advice handed out in a funny comment rather than the usual dry tone.

Comment: It's constructive in that it asserts a statement and provides some support for that statement.  It would probably be better with the beginning removed, and if that was *all* that there was then perhaps this would be NC, but as it is it's adding value, and therefore the mod was correct in not deleting it.

Comment: The delivery was unnecessarily boisterous but the message is sound, hence constructive.

Comment: I disagree that the message is 'sound'. Macros are a heavily contested thing, some people (myself included) like them, whilst others don't. Saying definitively that they are 'bad' is wrong, opinionated, and bad advice.

Comment: So, your solution to this is to... silence people?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Comments don't get deleted because they're opinionated, or even because they're wrong.  You can either choose to respond to it and explain why you feel what you did is an appropriate solution, or you can ignore the comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've just dismissed another flag on that comment. It has had two flags, both within the last two weeks.

I disagree that it is 'not constructive'.  It makes a point in a *colorful* way, but that doesn't make it 'not constructive'.  My criteria for constructive is (does not need all of these):

- Teaches something related to the post
- informs on a topic related to the post
- clarifies or corrects a problem with the post

This comment fulfills one of the above criteria.

A truly `not constructive` comment does not provide any support for a view, it just states a view, and in a way that does not make for constructive discussion (see what I did there?) For example:

- You don't know what you're talking about, n00b.
- C++ sucks.
- C is awesome.
- The preprocessor sucks.
- The Preprocessor is awesome.

All this having been said, comments are subject to deletion at any time, *for any reason*, so if you want something to stick around, edit it into an answer or the question (as appropriate).

Comment: FWIW, editing to remove all the caps and the "demon" part makes it *look* much more constructive.

Comment: @animuson That does solve the problem in my opinion. Thanks for the edit

Comment: What's the real difference between "The preprocessor sucks." and "Whenever there is a preprocessor and non-preprocessor way of accomplishing a single task, ALWAYS pick the non-preprocessor way!"?

Comment: Today I learned that lower case demons tend to get things done. Wait, is this a test?